# React.Js & Node.js No response from login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, authentication, axios

So i have managed to create a working signup form with react.js node and axios. I am using postgresql as database.
The problem comes when i want to login with store user. There were som error messages, but i fixed them all, now nothing happens.

This is from the backend.

```
app.post("/login", (req, res)=> {
const email = req.body.email;
const password = req.body.password;
try {
    pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?",
    [email],
    (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            res.send({err: err});
        }else{
            if(result.length > 0){
            res.send(result);
            bcrypt.compare(password, result.password, (error, response) => {
                console.log("Result is " + response + '\n');
            })
            }else{
                res.send({message: "Wrong email or password"});
            }
        }
    }

);
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Something went wrong..");
}})
```

The things i try to log in the console does not appear on submit.

Here is the front-end

```
<form action="/login" method="POST" onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
  <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
    <CssBaseline />
    <Box
      sx={{
        marginTop: 8,
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <Avatar sx={{ m: 1, bgcolor: 'secondary.main' }}>
        <LockOutlinedIcon />
      </Avatar>
      <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
        Login
      </Typography>
      <Box noValidate sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
        <TextField
          margin="normal"
          required
          fullWidth
          id="email"
          label="Email Address"
          name="email"
          value={email}
          onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          autoComplete="email"
          autoFocus
          variant="standard"
        />
        <TextField
          margin="normal"
          required
          fullWidth
          name="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          label="Password"
          type="password"
          id="password"
          autoComplete="current-password"
          variant="standard"
        />
        <Button
          type="submit"
          value="submit"
          onClick={() => onSubmitForm}
          fullWidth
          variant="contained"
          sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
          style={{backgroundColor: "#282c34"}}
        >
          Log ind
        </Button>
        <Grid container>
          <Grid item xs>
            <Link href="/forgotpsw" variant="body2">
              Glemt password?
            </Link>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  </Container>
  </form>
```

Also the onSubmit that is being called is here

```
const onSubmitForm = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
        const response = await Axios.post('http://localhost:5000/login', {
            email,
            password,
        })
            .then

            //setSuccess(true)
            ();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

Any help would be appreciated, I can't seem to  find any soloution :(

Comment: `res.send(result);` causes the response to be sent and thus next code is not executed. Remove that line and check

Comment: Hmm, I've tried it did not work. Still no response at all either

Comment: Move the `res.send(result);` inside your `bcrypt.compare`. Also do `res.send({err: error});` in your catch block

Comment: Just getting hit with ReferenceError: error is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your backend

```
app.post("/login", (req, res)=> {
const email = req.body.email;
const password = req.body.password;
try {
    pool.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?",
    [email],
    (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            res.send({err: err});
        }else{
            if(result.length > 0){
            bcrypt.compare(password, result.password, (error, response) => {
                console.log("Result is " + response + '\n');
                // Send response after comparing passwords
                res.send(result);
            })
            }else{
                res.send({message: "Wrong email or password"});
            }
        }
    }

);
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Something went wrong..");
    // Send error to front-end
    res.send({err: error});
}})
```

Comment: Yeah that did something for sure, now i get an error from axios error code:"ERR_NETWORK"

Comment: @MellowMellow do you get any logs in the backend? Try to log the error from catch block

Comment: I tried, but i dont get any logs no.
        console.log(error);